# Substring equality

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, equality

This is a question that deals with `SUBSTRING` equality with Server 2008. In my problem I have a column called `LICNO` that deals with license numbers. These license numbers are formatted as the following:

```
LPC-907
LCSW-517
```

I am using `SUBSTRING` as follows:

```
CASE 
  WHEN SUBSTRING(LICNO,1,2) <> 'LA' THEN 'Architect'
  WHEN SUBSTRING(LICNO,1,4) = 'CAP' THEN 'Certified Public Assistant'
  WHEN SUBSTRING(LICNO,1,2) IS NULL  THEN 'None'
  ELSE 'Landscape Architect'
END AS LicenseType,
```

The stored procedure only returns Architect and Landscape Architect. Am I using SUBSTRING correctly?

Comment: If you're always starting at 1, `LEFT()` is more concise and intuitive IMHO. We can't really judge the quality of what the stored procedure returns unless we understand what the data looks like and what results you expect.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, if LICNO does not begin with LA, the statement will return Architect. So, if LICNO begins with CAP, it will return Architect. You need to find the correct order for your statements. Put <> 'LA' after the other conditions and before the ELSE.

Answer (score 2):

```
CASE 
  WHEN SUBSTRING(LICNO,1,2) = 'LA' THEN 'Landscape Architect'
  WHEN SUBSTRING(LICNO,1,3) = 'CAP' THEN 'Certified Public Assistant'
  WHEN SUBSTRING(LICNO,1,2) IS NULL  THEN 'None'
  ELSE 'Architect'
END AS LicenseType,
```

(following @Melanie)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be using the incorrect number of characters for the `SUBSTRING` function.  If you want the value to equal CAP, then I think you should be using 3 for the length.  Also, replace the order of your CASE statement:

```
CASE 
  WHEN SUBSTRING(LICNO,1,3) = 'CAP' THEN 'Certified Public Assistant'
  WHEN SUBSTRING(LICNO,1,2) IS NULL  THEN 'None'
  WHEN SUBSTRING(LICNO,1,2) <> 'LA' THEN 'Architect'
  ELSE 'Landscape Architect'
END AS LicenseType
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

Comment: It should also probably be `CPA` not `CAP`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand -- yeah, probably need to see some data as you suggested :)